# How can I print a range of pages?

Tags: vba, printing, ms-word

How can I print a range of pages? I think I am doing as is said in the documentation.

This is the code.

```vb
Sub Imprimir()
    MsgBox "Current Printer: " & ActivePrinter
    'It works:
    ' Print current page
    ActiveDocument.PrintOut Background:=False, Range:=wdPrintCurrentPage, PrintToFile:=False
    ' Print all the document.
    'ActiveDocument.PrintOut Background:=False
    
    'It does not work
    ' print a range of pages
    ' ActiveDocument.PrintOut Background:=False, Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Pages:="2-3"
    ' ActiveDocument.PrintOut Background:=False, Range:=wdPrintFromTo, From:="2", To:="3"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the document have multiple sections? Do the non-working statements print anything?

Comment: Hi charles, only one section and prints the full document. It looks as if it ignores the parameters. I am reviewing and there may be several sections in one of the documents. How can this be solve if it is the case?

Comment: Hi charles, you are great!!! All the day looking for the problem and the problem is that the document has one section in each page because it comes from a combined document. Now my problem change to quit sections in a document from VBA. Thank you!!

Comment: Both of those work fine here. You do not need to "quit" sections but identify them in your vba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
ActiveDocument.PrintOut Background:=False, Range:=wdPrintFromTo, From:="p2s3", To:="p3s2"
```

See the [part of my page on Sections](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Range) about this.

Comment: It works. YOU ARE AWESOME!!!  I found nothing about this anywhere. I want you always by my side ;-)  Thank you again, I was really stucked!!

Comment: Thanks. It took me years to learn about printing pages when there are sections. It is documented, I think, but I don't really know where.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result of what I did finally https://github.com/davidbuenov/CombinarCorrespondencia